# MySql, insert on duplicate update where

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, sql-update

I have a table (price_flow) which has 3 columns. I use to record the price flow of products:

```
row_id (int, primary, ai) | product_id (int) | price (int) | update_date (date)
1                         | 1234             | 302         | 2016-07-22
2                         | 923              | 153         | 2016-07-25
3                         | 1234             | 290         | 2016-07-28
4                         | 923              | 170         | 2016-07-28
5                         | 1111             | 111         | 2016-07-28
...
```

Basically, when the php script which search the product price runs, at the end it inserts in mysql table a new row (if it's new day) or update the row (if that date the product price was already recorded). So I used an "insert on duplicate update" query (table has a unique index on product_id x update_date). My query is:

```
$aid = 1234; //Model ID
$date = date('Y-m-d'); //Current date
$pmin = 210; //Price
$query = "INSERT INTO price_flow (model_id, update_date, price) 
VALUES($aid, '$date', $pmin) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE price=$pmin";
```

It works fine, but what I want to do now is update/insert price only if the price is coherent with the other prices of the same product (results found by the script are not always accurate). So I thought that price will never be less than a half of the previous one. So I used

```
$query = "INSERT INTO price_flow (model_id, update_date, price) 
SELECT $aid, $date, $pmin  FROM price_flow WHERE model_id=$aid AND price<".(2*$pmin)." 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE price=291 WHERE price <".(2*$pmin).";"
```

So, if last price inserted is not less than twice the new price (hence, new price is less or equal to a half of last price), it does't insert or update the new price.
There are two problems: 1) the syntax of query is wrong:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE price <420' at line 1
```

2) If it's a new product with no previous records, the new line is not inserted (because of this `SELECT $aid, $date, $pmin  FROM price_flow WHERE model_id=$aid AND price<".(2*$pmin)."`

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: **WARNING**: This code likely has a number of severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 2):

You have TWO `where` clauses, which is flat-out a syntax error. If you need to update that one field conditionally in the `on dupe key`, then do it like this:

```
... UPDATE price=IF(price < 2*$pmin, 291, price)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my first problem, any solutions on the second one?

Comment: no idea. probably  shouldn't try to mix the two types of queries. mysql can't really create rows out of nothing for a select like that. while you could try a union, it'd ALWAYS run as well, regardless of the main select's results.